# Python, turn floats to integers

Tags: python, integer, int

Ok, I know this question gets asked a lot, but often the responses are special case workarounds. I guess you could say that I'm trying to understand why this won't work in addition to how to get it to work.

```
# ---- Find Spring Rate ---- #
import math
import numpy as np
from pylab import plot, show, title, xlabel, ylabel, axis
import matplotlib as mpl
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
'''
F = Load
D = mean dia of Coil
d = wire dia
Na = # of active coils
G = Shear Modulus 
'''
F = 30 #lbf   Assumed load 
D = 0.423 #in Measured 
d = 0.055 #in Measured
#N_a = 2.75 
G = 11.85*10**(6) #psi  # pg 526 Table 10-5 - Machine Theory Book
E = 29.0*10**(6) #psi   # pg 526 Table 10-5 - Machine Theory Book

X1 = []
Y1 = []

for N_a in range(1,6,0.025):
    y = (8*F*D**(3)*N_a)/(d**(4)*G) 
    k = (d**(4)*G)/(8*D**(3)*N_a)   
    K=(F//y)
    # print("N_a =", N_a)
    # print("y=", y)
    # print("k=", k)
    # print("K=", K)
    # print('\n')
    X1.append(N_a)
    Y1.append(k)

print("X1=", X1)
print("Y1=", Y1)
```

When I run this code, I get the following

```
Spring_Rate_Mk1.py", line 25, in <module>
    for N_a in range(1,6,0.025):
TypeError: 'float' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

**What I've tried:**

1. np.arange()
   this seems to work, but it gives me values like these for X

X1= [1.0, 1.025, 1.0499999999999998, 1.0749999999999997, 1.0999999999999996, 1.1249999999999996, 1.1499999999999995, 1.1749999999999994, 1.1999999999999993, 1.2249999999999992, ... and so on]

2. I've tried N_a = int(N) and also int in pretty much anywhere else I could think of to put it
3. I've tried changing the division from / to //
4. breaking the equations in to parts

   ```
   A = (d**(4)*G)
   B = (8*D**(3)*N_a)
   k = A/B
   ```

Comment: how about math.floor()?

Comment: So you have `np.arange` working, but you're unhappy about floating point imprecision?

Answer (score 2):

`np.arange` works, you're just seeing the representation of the float.

And `range` doesn't work with a floating point step, but in your case that's easy to fix since the start & end points are actually integers.

Without `arange`, you could use an integer range and divide the value since `1/0.025` is `40` just multiply your bounds by `40` and apply the division just afterwards (using `40.0` just in case of python 2)

```
for N_a in range(40,240):
    N_a /= 40.0
    print(N_a)
```

prints:

```
1.0
1.025
1.05
1.075
1.1
1.125
1.15
1.175
1.2
1.225
1.25
1.275
1.3
1.325
1.35
```

and so on.... Dividing by a multiple of 10 and a power of 2 makes the result without representation error.